# how to select and change data in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using the following as a simple example in pandas:

dataframe

```
        height  animal
1       33      dog
2       22      cat
3       1000    elephant
4       35      dog
.
.
1000    45      dog
```

how can i select all dog strings and set them to 0?

iv tried:

```
df['name'][df['name'] == 'dog'] = 0
```

but unfortunately is did not work

Comment: `df.loc[df.animal == 'dog','animal'] = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Just using `replace`

```
df.replace({'dog':0})
```

EDIT

```
df['animal'].replace('dog', 0)
```

Comment: That alters other columns, use `df['animal'].replace('dog', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['animal'][df['animal'] == 'dog'] = 0
```